# Sum of infinite series $1+(1/3)^2+(1/9)^2...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know how to find the sum of infinite geometric series, but this one is something more so I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Assuming that this is in fact a geometric series, just take the ratio of two terms and the rest should be plug-n-chug.

Comment: $\left(\dfrac 1{3^k}\right)^2=\dfrac 1{3^{2k}}=\dfrac 1{9^k}$

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I guess my brain was dead and wasn’t thinking at all.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like  the series $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {9^{n}}$ and you know how to sum this.

Comment: This answer is based on guess work. Since you have not specified the general term of the series and did not tell us that the series is a geometric series there is no way of knowing what this series really is.

Answer (score 0):

$1+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{9^2}\cdot\cdot\cdot$
$=1+\frac19+\frac1{81}\cdot\cdot\cdot$

You should be able to solve the right side.